# Unable to copy bash file into another directory

Tags: docker-compose

I'm tinkering with Docker where I'm using:

`COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
 RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh`

Strangely, I'm getting error saying "no such file or directory" but
it is there.

when I call `docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d --build`
command I get this output:

```
Successfully built 36461c09191a
Successfully tagged testdriven-app_users:latest
testdriven-app_users-db_1 is up-to-date
Recreating testdriven-app_users_1 ... error

ERROR: for testdriven-app_users_1  Cannot start service users: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh\": stat /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown

ERROR: for users  Cannot start service users: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh\": stat /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

What can I try to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is thrown since you are trying to copy your file in a folder which does not exist in the filesystem, and that folder is : `entrypoint.sh`

You must change your `COPY` command to :
`COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app`

Your destination path is a `folder` therefore it must not include the name of your file.

Comment: It make sense to me. But getting the same error. No change.

Comment: Try to also add the `-c` flag to your `RUN` command : `RUN ./bin/bash/  -c "chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"`

Comment: OK this was my fault because I was calling `docker-compose -f docker-compose-**dev**.yml up -d --build` instead of `docker-compose -f docker-compose-**prod**.yml up -d --build` which contains different calls and parameters. Silly me. I'll upvote your answer as I can imagine your answer would be completely valid to very similar problem with copying files.

Comment: Hope my answer helped you , and if it solved your problem  please accept it :D